# Troubles with XAMPP(or?)

Tags: php, xampp

I just started taking a PHP course and I'm having a lot of difficulties. I won't get anywhere unless this is resolved.

I got the course files downloaded and added them to htdocs folder but I can't run any new files I created. I get

> Object not found! 404 error

I see them under `localhost/coursefiles/whtever.php`. I've google searched all day but can't find anyone else having this specific problem.

Would uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP work? This is extremely frustrating and making me crazy.

Comment: With XAMPP's control panel, check that Apache and MySQL is running? Also, to see your files after that, you have to use `http://localhost/` or possibly `http://127.0.0.1`. If you created a sub-directory containing all the files in htdocs, then you'll need to append that to the end of either one of those URLs.

Answer (score 0):

First Check  xampp manager Is your MySQL and Apache is in running state ? 
Then Type Localhost in your browser , if Xampp Homepage is Coming It means Xampp is working Fine!
And again Checj your course files Extension they should have .php extension (if they are php files).
*Create An folder In your Htdocs Folder With Abc(for example) and Write in browser's Url window "http://Localhost/Abc* 
if your Folder is opening and it's showing Files Then There must be a Problem with files! :)